# hlen and sizeof(struct ip) in ip_output.c

Tags: c, ip, sizeof

In ip_output there's 2 lines of code that I can't understand:

```
mhlen = sizeof(struct ip)
```

and

```
if (hlen > sizeof(struct ip)) { ...
```

why do we need to compare hlen which is the lengh of the original ip packet's header to the sizeof(struct ip) ?

can you please help?

Comment: You're the one with the code in front of you, not us.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maybe this is from BSD's ip_fragment function?  one of those variables is `mhlen`, and one is `hlen`, so they could be different.  The IP header is variable length.  The `struct ip` has the fixed portion.  The `hlen` variable has the actual length including the variable length options at the end.

Comment: yes actually they are 2 variables, i dont care about the first, actually what i dont understand is why they are comparing the header lengh to sizeof(struct ip)? do u know what is the answer of sizeof(struct ip)?
thank you for your answer by the way*

Comment: Hey, sorry elie, just saw this.  `sizeof(struct ip)` is always 20.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header for details on the header layout, which should help you decode the code.

Answer (score 0):

IP headers can have additional options (e.g. *source route record*, for tracerouting). The total size of the IP header is encoded in the `hlen` field as a number of 32 bit words, so it will be 5 (for 20 bytes) if there are no IP options, and greater if there are IP options.